# python eve gracefully exit from callback

Tags: python-3.x, eve

I'm wondering if it's possible to update an item without completely process the PATCH request.

What I'm trying to do is to randomly generate and insert a value inside the db when a user sends a PATCH request to the accounts/ endpoint.
If I don't exit from the PATCH request I will get an error because it expects a value but I cannot give it in advance because it will be randomly generated.

```
def pre_accounts_patch_callback(request, lookup):
        if not my_func():
            abort(401)
        else:
            return HTTP 201 OK
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you want to achieve, however keep in mind that you can actually update `lookup` within your callback, so the API will get back and process the updated version, with validation and all.

```
import random

def pre_accounts_patch_callback(request, lookup):
    lookup['random_field'] = random.randint(0, 10)

app = Eve()
app.on_pre_PATCH_accounts += pre_accounts_patch_callback

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```